# Dynamic Denominator

Tags: sql, sql-server

For lack of a better term, I'm searching for a way to dynamically alter a denominator to better account for dynamic changes to inventory levels relative to an ideal inventory.

I can't verbalize this particularly well, so perhaps an example will help.

Say a company holds a particular inventory.  This inventory can fluctuate due to sales and potentially be oversupplied at times.  This inventory is often checked against an ideal inventory level, and parts will be purchased from suppliers when these inventories fall below a certain level, as compared to the ideal model relative to the overall value.  I.e. if the current inventory holds 3% of Part 1, but the ideal inventory indicates we should be holding 5% of Part 1, we know we need to purchase more of Part 1.

Pretty straight forward, except in cases where the supplier is unable to provide more parts.  So our current inventory contains varying numbers of Parts 1-10 (as does the ideal inventory).  However two of the parts in our current inventory we need more of, but the supplier can't supply any more.

Because we can't order any more of these parts, for the sake of calculating the relative inventory of other parts, we need to adjust the value of the out-of-stock parts to be in line with the ideal inventory. Let's assume we do this by taking the ideal inventory level (e.g. 5%) relative to the overall value of all items in inventory on a dollar basis.  We then take the difference between this ideal inventory level per part relative to the current inventory level, and add in that value to our existing inventory (per part) for out-of-stock items.  This final value gives us the adjusted total value of all items in inventory with which to use to determine inventory items to prioritize purchase of (for items that are in stock with our suppliers).

The issue, as demonstrated below, is that the theoretical adjustments being made on the basis of out-of-stock items is based on a denominator that is calculated on the initial inventory value rather than the adjusted inventory value. Therefore the out-of-stock items whose overall weight was adjusted to be in line with the ideal inventory levels is off.

Is there a way to dynamically account for adjustments that ultimately result in a relative weight for those out-of-stock items that are in line with the ideal inventory?

```
DECLARE @Inventory TABLE
    (PartID VARCHAR(10),
    Quantity FLOAT
    )

DECLARE @JITInventory TABLE
    (PartID VARCHAR(10),
    Quantity FLOAT,
    isOutOfStock BIT
    )

DECLARE @Price TABLE
    (PartID VARCHAR(10),
    Price FLOAT)

Insert Into @Inventory VALUES
    ('Part 1','10'),
    ('Part 2','15'),
    ('Part 3','10'),
    ('Part 4','12'),
    ('Part 5','9'),
    ('Part 6','8'),
    ('Part 7','6'),
    ('Part 8','13'),
    ('Part 9','14'),
    ('Part 10','18')

Insert Into @JITInventory VALUES
    ('Part 1','15000',1),
    ('Part 2','18067',0),
    ('Part 3','6776',0),
    ('Part 4','10000',0),
    ('Part 5','14455',1),
    ('Part 6','4517',0),
    ('Part 7','22586',0),
    ('Part 8','6776',0),
    ('Part 9','994',0),
    ('Part 10','1355',0)

Insert Into @Price VALUES
    ('Part 1','10'),
    ('Part 2','15'),
    ('Part 3','10'),
    ('Part 4','12'),
    ('Part 5','9'),
    ('Part 6','8'),
    ('Part 7','6'),
    ('Part 8','13'),
    ('Part 9','14'),
    ('Part 10','18')        
    ;


--ideal inventory level as percentage of total
SELECT
    jit.partid,
    jit.Quantity,
    p.Price,
    Net=Quantity*Price,
    Wt=(Quantity*Price)/
        SUM(Quantity*Price) OVER(Partition By 1),
    isOutOfStock
Into #JITInv
FROM @JITInventory jit
    join @Price p
    on jit.PartID=p.PartID


--current inventory level
SELECT
    I.partid,
    I.Quantity,
    p.Price,
    Net=Quantity*Price,
    Wt=(Quantity*Price)/
        SUM(Quantity*Price) OVER(Partition By 1)
Into #Inv
FROM @Inventory I
    join @Price p
    on I.PartID=p.PartID

--knowing we can't order more out of stock items from 
--the supplier, adjust the items we can't control 
--to be in line with our ideal inventory by 
--temporarily assuming we're purchasing those items
--to be held at the same weight as the ideal inventory.
--  i.e. take the weight of the parts in the ideal
--  inventory and multiply by the total value
--  of the current inventory to get
--  the value of the part IDs we assume are 
--  in stock so that the weights of other parts
--  aren't impacted.
SELECT
    J.PartID,
    J.Wt*(Select SUM(NET) FROM #Inv) as JITValue,
    I.Net as IValue,
    J.Wt*(Select SUM(NET) FROM #Inv)-I.Net as Adjustment
INTO #InvAdjust
FROM #Inv I
    JOIN #JITInv J
    ON I.PartID=J.PartID
WHERE isOutOfStock=1
```

And the result of the comparison of those items that are out of stock at the supplier in our current inventory relative to the adjusted value based on ideal inventory:

```
PartID  JITValue          IValue    Adjustment
Part 1  208.167374863295    100       108.167374863295
Part 5  180.543564218936    81        99.5435642189359
```

Then recalculate the value of all positions assuming we've purchased the out-of-stock items to create a baseline where remaining in-stock items at our supplier can then be prioritized to purchase.

```
--Now using the adjusted value to be in line with the ideal (JIT) model,
--determine the new parts weights to determine how we should
--prioritize buying/selling items that aren't currently out of stock.

--Issue here is because the adjustment of Parts 1 and 5 are relative
--to the current value of the inventory, the weights are once again
--skewed from the ideal inventory level.
SELECT
    I.PartID,
    I.Net CurrentNet,
    I.Net+COALESCE(IA.Adjustment,0) as NewNet,
    (I.Net+COALESCE(IA.Adjustment,0))
        /SUM(I.Net+COALESCE(IA.Adjustment,0)) OVER(Partition By 1) AS NewWt,
    J.Wt as JITWt

FROM #Inv I
  LEFT JOIN #InvAdjust IA
   ON I.PartID=IA.PartID
  JOIN #JITInv J
   ON J.PartID=I.PartID
```